# Images: wrong permissions and owner is 99 - no thumbnail

Tags: file-manager

All of my images have no thumbnail preview in the CP.

All images uploaded are automatically set to:
666
Owner: 99
Group: 99

I can't change it through ftp or the the Media Temple file manager

EE: v 2.92
Media Temple DV server

I do have assets installed but I'm not sure if that matters

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to change your uploads directory permissions. The non-generation of thumbnails pretty much verifies that it is a permissions problem.

First, take a general look at the [EE Upgrade Instructions](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/installation/update.html), in particular the section on [Verify File Permissions](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/installation/update.html#verify-file-permissions). Check everything matches the recommendations.

Then check your **File Manager Permissions** in `Control Panel > Content > Files`. Make sure you have your upload directory defined.

Finally, if you are allowing users to upload files via the Control Panel, the web server daemon `user:group` (typically `apache:apache` or `www:www`) needs to have write permission to the uploads directory. Try to avoid making permissions 777 (which is global read/write/execute) and just enable read/write for the web server daemon. This should be a simple check and fix that you can do via your FTP agent. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for the response, but I had already tried that. The issue seems to be with thumbnails generated by EE.  I also can't change the ownership or permissions on these files through ftp or cpanel.

Comment: According to the Media Temple FileManager [docs](http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/427/Managing+your+files+with+File+Manager#gs/-instructions--) you can modify both file and folder permissions. You should just be able to modify permissions of the **thumbnails** directory using it.

Comment: The **thumbnails** directory will be in the following location on your server: `/path/to/eesite/images/uploads/_thumbs`. So you want `images/uploads` (and any subdirectory) to have write permission by the web server.